# Btrfs check repair give device busy. How to see what it keeps busy?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, block-device

I am in a chicken-egg situation for my secondary harddrive (non boot):

- My BTRFS mount has gone readonly because **no space left**.
- `btrfs filesystem resize` only works on mounted volumes.
- I needed to umount this ro mount in force mode (because of device busy).
- If I try to mount rw it fails because of errors (most likely caused by no space left)
- If I try to run `btrfs check --repair` it gives device busy

What to do to find out what keeps `/dev/sda` busy? My hdd is listed in `/etc/fstab`, does that matter (`UUID=262a8d86-279a-4f6b-8968-32e200c32255 /mnt/hdd   btrfs defaults,compress=zlib 0      1`)???

I tried:

- `lsof | grep /dev/s` -> nothing
- `lsof | grep /mnt/hdd`-> nothing
- The same for `fuser` -> nothing

So:

`mount -o recovery /dev/sda /mnt/hdd`

> [63035.539792] BTRFS error (device sda): Remounting read-write after
>   error is not allowed

If I try to run:

```
root@myhost:/mnt# btrfs check --repair /dev/sda
enabling repair mode
ERROR: cannot open device '/dev/sda': Device or resource busy
ERROR: cannot open file system
```

Answer (score 0):

from https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfsck
It is highly recommended to get the latest version of btrfs-tools and recover important data with:

```
mount -o recovery,ro /dev/sda /mnt/hda
btrfs restore
```

before you:
    btrfs check --repair

**Mounting ro is whats recommended.**